# State object overwrites previous child when producing a new one

Tags: java, state, backtracking

I am using backtracking in a framework to work a graph-coloring problem with bound-pruning. 
Each possible state of the graph (i.e. each combination of colors one could put on the graph) is represented by a State object. The framework asks each State to produce all of it's children, chooses the one with the best bounds, and repeats to find the best solution, pruning by bounds along the way. The trouble I'm running into is this:

When I call nextChild() on a State, it changes the previous child produced by that state to be identical to the one just produced.

Here is what I believe to be the relevant part of my code:

```
    public State nextChild() {
//      System.out.println("currentColor: "+ colors.get(currentColor) + " firstUncolored " + this.firstUncolored);
//      previous line for debugging
        GraphColoringState child = childSetup();
        child.gcolors[firstUncolored] = colors.get(currentColor++);
        if(this.currentColor == colors.size()){
            this.currentColor = 0;
            this.hasMoreChildren = false;
        }
        return child;
    }

private GraphColoringState childSetup() {
        GraphColoringState theClone = new GraphColoringState(graph, colors);
        theClone.gcolors = this.gcolors;
        theClone.firstUncolored = this.firstUncolored +1;
        theClone.currentColor = 0;
        return theClone;
    }
```

When I produce and print children like this:

```
State s = new GraphColoringState(graph, colors);
System.out.println(s);

State s1 = s.nextChild();
System.out.println(s1);

State s2 = s.nextChild();
System.out.println(s2);

State s3 = s.nextChild();
System.out.println(s3);
```

I get this output:

```
    , , , , , , 
Red, , , , , , 
Green, , , , , , 
Blue, , , , , ,
```

but when I produce and print this way:

```
System.out.println(s);

State s1 = s.nextChild();
State s2 = s.nextChild();
State s3 = s.nextChild();

System.out.println(s1);
System.out.println(s2);
System.out.println(s3);
```

I get this unfortunate output:

```
, , , , , , 
Blue, , , , , , 
Blue, , , , , , 
Blue, , , , , ,
```

I say this output is unfortunate, because in order for the backtracking framework to work, I need to store all of these children at the same time, with different values. I have tried using an array instance variable within each State to store its children, but to no avail.

Why does my code change the values of the children I have already produced?

Please and Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

gcolors is an array that you set as a value of the new child

```
theClone.gcolors = this.gcolors;
```

Then you modify gcolors in nextChild()

```
child.gcolors[firstUncolored] = colors.get(currentColor++);
```

To avoid such errors you could use an unmodifiable list instead.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand - should I make the gcolors variable final? Since my code is trying to modify it as is, wouldn't that just throw an exception?

Comment: If you want to retain the older children then you must not overwrite their state. You could make the GraphColoringState immutable by making all variables final and replacing the gcolors array by a list. Make sure the list is also immutable by wrapping it into an unmodifiable list by calling Collections.unmodifiableList(..). This way it is impossible that you accidentally change the state of the previous child. But, the original error seems to be that you reuse the gcolors array for the copy and then modify this.

Comment: I see. 
Well, I've found a solution - I simply changed the line 
theClone.gcolors = this.gcolors; 
to read
theClone.gcolors = this.gcolors.clone();
Very simple really, I probably didn't need to bother y'all with it.

Thank you for the advice, and have a great day!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the problem was in this line:

```
 theClone.gcolors = this.gcolors;
```

This caused all of the States to share one array denoting the color of each node. What I actually wanted was for each State to have it's own array.

Changing that line to:

```
theClone.gcolors = this.gcolors.clone();
```

was all that was needed. Thank you all for your help!